# Centos8 root Network drive is full, need to increase space

Tags: filesystems, lvm, samba

I have installed Samba on centos8 in order to enable sharing for windows systems. I have 2 HDDs already installed having 1 TB each drive. I installed a new drive also which is 2TB. The problem I am facing is.... the root that is shared via samba is 50GB only and it is already full. I want to increase the sharing space either by using the same directory or using my new HD. I am new to all this and need help.

### responses to comments and answers

```
[root@localhost ~]# lsblk -f
NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID MOUNTPOINT
sda
 ├─sda1 ext4 e3f4c534--45f9-27 /boot
 └─sda2 LVM2_member fYaqdFF4d
    ├─cl-root xfs f8038c-6c1e3 /
    ├─cl-swap swap f14722-ae7 [SWAP]
    └─cl-home xfs 026070929 /home
sdb
 └─sdb1 LVM2_member AP6buf--XQgD3
    └─cl-home xfs 0261042a929 /home
sdc
```

Comment: could you share the output of `fdisk -l` and `lsblk -f`

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# lsblk -f
NAME        FSTYPE      LABEL UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                  
├─sda1      ext4              e3f4c534--45f9-27   /boot
└─sda2      LVM2_member       fYaqdFF4d 
  ├─cl-root xfs               f8038c-6c1e3   /
  ├─cl-swap swap              f14722-ae7   [SWAP]
  └─cl-home xfs               026070929   /home
sdb                                                                  
└─sdb1      LVM2_member       AP6buf--XQgD3 
  └─cl-home xfs               0261042a929   /home
sdc

Comment: comments section does not accept all characters nor it accepts screenshot to share the full results

Comment: @Nazia This is one of the reasons why you are requested to [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/599462/edit) your post to include details asked for by contributors, rather than adding them as comments ...

Comment: Please remove `lvm` tag because you do not appear to have an lvm setup. How large would you want the share to become ? It would be cleaner to copy the data with "retain permissions" over to sdc (which I assume is the new disk), then change the path in the `smb.conf` file (make a backup first) and test your configuration with `testparm` . It looks like sdc does not have a partition, yet, create one for the share.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your Samba share is on the root partition.  If you expect this to be the largest section, you can:

- Copy the entire contents of the Samba share to the 2TB drive.
- Delete the contents of the old Samba share, but keep the folder.  E.g. If your share is in `/opt/samba`, delete everything inside `/opt/samba` but keep the folder.
- Mount the 2TB drive at `/opt/samba`.  You can do this temporarily with the `mount` command; if you want this to persist, you can edit the `/etc/fstab` file.  I can't be more specific with what you've shared thus far, but as Heysus says in the comments above, posting the output of those commands will let people help you better.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I am very new to all this, it would be great if you share the commands to do that

Comment: I already have the backup so if data is deleted it won't affect but I need to increase the sharing storage space. How can I make my 2TB HDD as shared drive with samba when one is already shared? I want to unshare the existing space.

Comment: @Nazia Unlike Windows, which has a separate drive letter (C:, D:, etc.) for each physical drive, Linux has one single file system.  So you say, "Put this partition at this place in the file system" with the `mount` command.  So you can mount all 2TB in the current Samba folder.  However, if you mount on an existing folder, you can no longer access the contents of that folder, which is why you need to copy it to the 2TB and delete it from the original location.